# Как получить доступ к хранилищу store Redux в useSelector?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Доброго времени суток всем!

Когда я хочу получить доступ к состояниям моего приложения в компоненте, я использую useSelector и это круто. Но когда я использую этот прием, я не получаю "подсказок". Я получаю доступ к состоянию используя внутренние знания структуры проета, но когда хранилище стало совсем большим, мне постоянно приходится смотреть иерархию моего store, что не очень удобно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я бы хотел видеть "подсказки/автодополнение" например так же, как когда я описываю редюсеры при создании среза.

[image: Slice]

Заранее спасибо :))

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось что достаточно использовтаь TypeScript )

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]